Telegram WebApp hash verification mismatch despite correct data and bot token in Node.js
Issue:
I'm trying to verify the integrity of the hash provided by the Telegram WebApp authentication flow using Node.js, but the calculated hash never matches the provided hash. I'm using the correct bot token, and the parameters (userId, username, authDate) seem to be correct and properly formatted. Despite this, the hash mismatch persists.

Telegram Parameters:
Here are the values I'm receiving from Telegram's WebApp (logged from my frontend):

User ID: 1234567890
Username: random_user123
Auth Date: 1727134170
Provided Hash: 55f0a395c4851512b31a797e33494801f4ff3f31ad99da3d92f13dfcccf678f0


Telegram Bot Token:
I’m using a bot token generated in the testnet environment, defined in
TELEGRAM_BOT_TOKEN


My Approach:
Following Telegram's official documentation, I’m constructing the data_check_string and calculating the HMAC-SHA256 hash as follows:

Node.js Code:
const crypto = require('crypto');

function verifyTelegramHash({ userId, username, authDate, hash }) {
  if (!userId || !username || !authDate || !hash) {
    throw new Error('Missing required parameters');
  }

  // Log parameters for debugging
  console.log('Verifying Telegram hash with:', { userId, username, authDate, hash });

  // Create the secret key using SHA-256 with the Telegram bot token
  const secretKey = crypto.createHash('sha256')
    .update('process.env.TELEGRAM_BOT_TOKEN', 'utf8')
    .digest();

  // Construct the dataCheckString in alphabetical order of the keys
  const dataCheckString = `auth_date=${authDate}&id=${userId}&username=${username}`;

  console.log('Data Check String:', dataCheckString);

  // Calculate the hash using HMAC-SHA256
  const calculatedHash = crypto
    .createHmac('sha256', secretKey)
    .update(dataCheckString)
    .digest('hex');

  console.log('Calculated Hash:', calculatedHash);
  console.log('Provided Hash:', hash);

  // Return whether the hashes match
  return calculatedHash === hash;
}

// Example usage:
const isValid = verifyTelegramHash({
  userId: '1234567890',
  username: 'random_user123',
  authDate: '1727134170',
  hash: '55f0a395c4851512b31a797e33494801f4ff3f31ad99da3d92f13dfcccf678f0'
});

console.log('Is the hash valid?', isValid);


Output:
Here’s the output I’m seeing:
Verifying Telegram hash with: {
  userId: '1234567890',
  username: 'random_user123',
  authDate: '1727134170',
  hash: '55f0a395c4851512b31a797e33494801f4ff3f31ad99da3d92f13dfcccf678f0'
}
Data Check String: auth_date=1727134170&id=1234567890&username=random_user123
Calculated Hash: a97dc385905f5e09258ec19276751ab7fff55bc6bfe5e48a74151a502ac73b09
Provided Hash: 55f0a395c4851512b31a797e33494801f4ff3f31ad99da3d92f13dfcccf678f0
Is the hash valid? false


What I’ve Tried:

Environment variables: I’ve hardcoded the bot token in the code to eliminate issues with environment variables.
String formatting: I’ve ensured that the dataCheckString is correctly ordered and formatted (alphabetically by keys and no extra spaces).
Bot token: Double-checked that the bot token is correct (it’s the same one used in my Telegram bot, currently in test mode. I also tried the main one).
Checked Telegram docs: I followed Telegram's documentation to calculate the hash using HMAC-SHA256 and verify the signature.


Expected Behavior:
The calculated hash should match the hash provided by Telegram, but this is not happening.

Question:
What could be causing the mismatch between the calculated and provided hash? Is there something I’m missing in the way Telegram WebApp hashes should be calculated?

The documentation you link says to separate the fields by 'line feed' characters nowadays usually called 'newline' characters (and that's the definition they hyperlink!) NOT ampersands

were you ever able to solve this? Running into the same problem
